# (UPDATED) psycopg2 [Import Error] on Windows - ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__psycopg)

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, importerror

[UPDATE] - An antivirus software installed on my computer was causing the issue. Disabling it solved the problem :)

I'm getting a weird error when I try to import psycopg2.

Using Python 3.7.7

Downloaded psycopg2 using pip

$ python -m pip install psycopg2

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.8.5
```

> import psycopg2
>
> if **name** =="**main**":
>       print("Hello World!")

Running the code gives me the below error:

```
$ python test2.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2   
File "C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__psycopg)
```

Have tried installing pscopg2-binary instead. Still getting the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: 1. Did you explicitly _uninstall_ `psycopg2` before installing `psycopg2-binary`?  2.  Is that the _complete_ error traceback?  You seem to be reporting a comment used to tell linters to ignore a line, not the actual error.